# Eclipse RCP, translate the dependency plugins

Tags: eclipse, rcp

When I am developing an Eclipse RCP application, what is the easiest way to translate those strings in the plugins required by my application into Chinese? As I know, these plugins already have a Chinese version at Babel project. How can I use the existing Babel translations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Babel from its [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.8.1/helios). Then restart eclipse, it will use the language corresponding to your system locale, or launch eclipse with `-nl <locale>` [option](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Babel_/_Installing_Language_Packs)